# Setting the 'this' context of an anonymous function within a JQuery Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, jquery-events

I want to pass a specific context the the following click bound method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var o = {
        name : 'I\'m object O'
    };

    $('#my-button').click(function(){
        alert(this.name);
    }.call(o));
});
```

The problem is that this gets triggered as soon as the page loads. Is there a way I can bind a context to the anonymous function of the click handler and have it trigger only when the click event is fired? Also can you explain why its been triggered on the page load rather than the click event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
$("#my-button").click($.proxy(function () {
   alert(this.name);
}, o));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are calling this anonymous function at the time of it's declaration. Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var o = {
        name : 'I\'m object O'
    };

    $('#my-button').click(function(){
        function(){
            alert(this.name);
        }.call(o)
    });
    /*
     * Or shorter:
     * $('#my-button').click(function(){
     *     alert(o.name);
     * });
     */
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer too. Upvoted as it explains why the issue I was having occurred as well as how to get around it in vanilla js :)

Answer (score 0):

$(document).mousedown(function(e){

//Do stuff

}

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question.